# A word for when you speak ill of something and it turns out the person you are speaking to likes that thing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Is there a word describing the phenomenon of when you insult or speak badly of something but it turns out the person you are speaking to likes or owns or is related to that thing? E.G. you say "The new model of XYZ looks terrible" and the person you are speaking to says "Oh... I've just gotten one."

Comment: this word needs a word

Comment: @Matt - agreed, there are words as suggested in the good answers below, but they are more general than this.

Comment: I think that @JoeTaxpayer 's point is an important one; none of the words below refers *specifically* to your situation.  I want very much to call this hockey-itis, per the second half of https://reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/2kfcud/a_man_goes_into_a_supermarket_to_buy_a_half_head (but, to be explicit, that isn't, and shouldn't be, a word).

Comment: You *slam-boozled* yourself! *Embarraslamming*. You performed a *dis-crash* ("dis" as in "disrespect"). *dis-fail*? *Inappropri-insulting*. *Trash-talk-block*. Wheeeee!

Comment: I call it good sport. As in I probably said it knowing their connection to it. Too many years working construction, I guess. But if you suddenly discover what you said ended up [hitting close to home](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64224/close-to-home-quite-accurate), by all means explain yourself at great length and enjoy the moment :o

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "unfortunate".

Comment: The phrase "oh no ... I've spoken out of turn" is sometimes used here.  Or just "oh-oh .. I've said the wrong thing."  It's true there is not, precisely, an SWR or phrase forf this particular foot-in-mouth moment.  There should be!

Comment: From your title (and to some extent, from your description), I thought you were referring to [Insult Backfire](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InsultBackfire), but apparently that's not what it was about.

Comment: reminds me of "one mans trash is another man's treasure".

Comment: also, if the thing you dislike is something you are not very knowledgeable of, and the other person is, you may be "speaking out of school" (http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-spe4.htm)

Comment: @chiliNUT "speaking out of school" was not what I was looking for but that is an excellent term. In Japanese we have 知ったかぶり [shitta kaburi] which is basically the same thing - it's nice to know the English equivalent.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Not a word, but a phrase; **[put your foot in it/your mouth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_one%27s_foot_in_one%27s_mouth)**, also known as **[Foot-in-Mouth disease](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foot-in-mouth_disease#English)** which plays on Foot-*and*-Mouth disease, an ailment which afflicts cattle.

> Example 
>   I was talking to the boss about the new XYZ and I really put my foot in it, I didn't know he'd just bought one of the hideous things!

Comment: Be careful of * every time he opens his mouth he puts his foot in it*.

Comment: I've also heard the phrase "eat crow" to mean this same thing. I don't know if crow is some synonym for feet or not.

Comment: @corsiKa "Eating crow" involves being humiliated by having to admit you were in the wrong. Because eating crow required that admission or error it is subtly different from putting your foot in it, where no admission is required. Also putting your foot in it is more about being tactless than being wrong.

Comment: I'd say this is pretty close what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: yes, "eat crow" is totally different.

Comment: Late response, but... "put your foot in your mouth" and "put your foot in it", while both serviceable for this use, are a bit different.  "foot in mouth" is more of an "I shouldn't have said that", while "putting your foot in it" ('it' in this instance being something an animal left on the ground) is more of an "I'm in trouble now".

Comment: @user112358 I clearly don't agree and the citation links I've included back up my view. Please feel free to provide support for your perspective on it.

Comment: Spagirl - I'll concede, as I have no references except many years of being alive and talking to people.  I note that wiktionary has no origins for "foot in it", and you must admit that putting your foot in a pile of doo-doo could be embarrassing..

Comment: Also, it appears that "putting your foot in it" is sometime used to mean putting extra effort into your cooking.

Comment: @user112358 Putting ones foot in one's mouth, is a subset of putting one's foot in an undefined 'it'. While an undefined 'it' may be a mouth, a mouth may not be an undefined 'it'. I'm very uncertain as to exactly what point you are seeking to make.

Answer (score 43):

A good phrase would be [**faux pas**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/faux-pas)

> a slip or blunder in etiquette, manners, or conduct; an embarrassing social blunder or indiscretion.

*Dictionary.com*

While it's not as highly specific as your scenario I believe it would still fall under a faux pas.

Comment: This is a bit more general than just applying to the situation the OP is seeking it for

Answer (score 37):

I don't think English has a word for the precise situation you are after, but have you considered [**gaffe**](https://www.google.com/search?q=gaffe):

> an unintentional act or remark causing embarrassment to its originator; a blunder.
>
> *synonyms*:   blunder, mistake, error, slip, faux pas, indiscretion, impropriety, miscalculation, gaucherie, solecis, slip-up, howler, boo-boo, fluff, flub, blooper, goof
>
> *"I made some real gaffes at work"*

Comment: Definitely a good word for this sort of thing, but yes I'm looking for something more specific to describe the situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Make a ***blunder*** (to make a gross mistake / error due to stupidity or carelessness (OED)) or ***goof*** (to blunder / make a mistake (OED)).

So,

"I really blundered / goofed when I said... (the new model of XYZ looks terrible).

Answer (score -1):

Well he certainly [*turned the tables*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-the-tables-on-sb) on you. This expression can be used to summarize the fact that he used your negativity against you.

Comment: a citation from a dictionary such as this one, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-the-tables-on-sb helps support an answer.

Comment: -1, This doesn't seem right at all. Also, I had to click the link to see the definition, and for all I know there's some alternate definition you intended that I missed. Beside linking the source, you should copy over the specific definition you're looking for.